# custom django-user object has no attribute 'has_module_perms'

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

My custom user model for login via email:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    is_superuser = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True,max_length=75)
    is_staff = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    is_active = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=None)

    # Use default usermanager
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

For which, I'm able to successfully create a superuser. However, when I try to login with email and password, I get this error:

```
'MyUser' object has no attribute 'has_module_perms'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your User implementation is not providing the mandatory methods to be used with the Admin module.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin.

In your case, add the permissions mixin (PermissionsMixin), as a superclass of your model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
     # ...
```

It is described here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions

It works with Django 1.x, 2.x, 3.x and 4.x.

EDIT: updated links to django version 4.0

Comment: This doesn't work on newer versions of Django. See answer below.

Comment: It does, confirmed on 2.1

Answer (score 18):

I think your model is missing some attributes such as 'has_module_params'...Try to add the following

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
  ...
  ...

  def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_superuser

  def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return self.is_superuser
```

Answer (score 5):

For those who are just stepping in November 2017 and after, I don't think adding or allowing your class to inherit `PermissionsMixin` is the way out, being that it will raise more error since you have reinvented the wheel.

I ran into the same problem this afternoon (4th Nov, 2017) having override `Username` with `Phone Number`:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    ..
    ..

    def create_superuser(self, phone, password=None):
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError("provide password please")
        myuser = self.model(phone=phone)
        myuser.set_password(password)
        myuser.is_admin = True
        myuser.is_staff = True
        myuser.save()

        return myuser
```

So, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` wasn't working and kept raising `object has no attribute 'has_module_perms'` error, the following is how I fixed mine:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ..
    ..

    def get_full_name(self):
        pass

    def get_short_name(self):
        pass

    @property
    def is_superuser(self):
        return self.is_admin

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
       return self.is_admin

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
       return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
       return self.is_admin

    @is_staff.setter
    def is_staff(self, value):
        self._is_staff = value
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This answer is identical to @Bogdan Goie's. But you are using `is_admin` instead of `is_superuser`. That's potentially confusing.