# django - TypeError at /admin/login/ has_module_perms() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I get an error when I login `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin`.
I don't know where the error occurred.

This is the error message:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.2
Installed Applications:
['users',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/c/Softwares/anaconda3/envs/medic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/c/Softwares/anaconda3/envs/medic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/c/Softwares/anaconda3/envs/medic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/c/Softwares/anaconda3/envs/medic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/c/Softwares/anaconda3/envs/medic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in login
  382.             self.each_context(request),

File "/home/c/Softwares/anaconda3/envs/medic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in each_context
  302.             'available_apps': self.get_app_list(request),

File "/home/c/Softwares/anaconda3/envs/medic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in get_app_list
  470.         app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)

File "/home/c/Softwares/anaconda3/envs/medic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in _build_app_dict
  418.             has_module_perms = model_admin.has_module_permission(request)

File "/home/c/Softwares/anaconda3/envs/medic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in has_module_permission
  506.         return request.user.has_module_perms(self.opts.app_label)

File "/home/c/Softwares/anaconda3/envs/medic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in has_module_perms
  422.         return _user_has_module_perms(self, module)

File "/home/c/Softwares/anaconda3/envs/medic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in _user_has_module_perms
  196.             if backend.has_module_perms(user, app_label):

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: has_module_perms() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

users/views.py:
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from .forms import RegisterForm

```
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def register(request):
    redirect_to = request.POST.get('next', request.GET.get('next', ''))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            if redirect_to:
                return redirect(redirect_to)
            else:
                return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context={'form': form, 'next': redirect_to})
```

this is a user login registration authentication code, and only have user app.
in the traceback seem the error didn't occured in my code, so i don't know where it is wrong.

user/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email',
                              unique=True, error_messages={'unique': 'Email is already occupied'})

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        pass
```

Comment: Is this a custom User model? If yes, please post your model.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370333/custom-django-user-object-has-no-attribute-has-module-perms)

Comment: thanks for your help.I have solved this problem and it's something wrong with my users/backends.py.

Answer (score 0):

If use an AbstractBaseUser add arguments, or try overwriting the function, can use this:

```
def has_module_perms(self, *args): # or add
    # ....
    return True
```