# Django custom user 'Account' object has no attribute 'has_module_perms'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, backend

I create a custom user model to login via email, but i got some issue when im tried to login on admin channel

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
class MyAccountManajer(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')
        
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('User must have an username')

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, password):
         user = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            password= password,
            username = username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
         )
         user.is_admin = True
         user.is_active = True
         user.is_staff = True
         user.is_superadmin = True
         user.save(using=self.db)
         return user
```

I'm able to create a superuser. However, when I try to login with email. I got this Error
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    'Account' object has no attribute 'has_module_perms'
Exception Location: ....\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py, line 241, in inner

Can someone fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the "PermissionsMixin" to your class to obtain the method you need

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin 

class MyAccountManajer(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
```

You can find the answer to a similar question asked here: [custom django-user object has no attribute 'has_module_perms'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370333/custom-django-user-object-has-no-attribute-has-module-perms)

Comment: it works, in my first try i ca'tn edited in django admin but the problem is i forget delete some file thank ToT

Comment: Happy it's working! If this is what solved your problem, check it as the answer. If not, write an answer and check it to help people facing the same issue.